# Cookie redirection issue after submit (form)

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, cookies, aweber

I have an issue with a redirect I am trying to add on a website. I am not a big expert so that's why I am asking for kind help.

Before showing the code here are the issues, and how I wanted this to work.

So, I have an Aweber form added to my site with two fields Name and Email + the submit button. Basically, if a submission is successful the user would be redirected to another page and a cookie would set in.

What's with the cookie?

Well the form is on **website.com**, and if a user gets subscribed he is redirected **website.com/whatever.html**

Also, if he subscribed, the next time he enters **website.com** he will be automatically redirected on **website.com/whatever.html**

Ok, so I got this main idea to work but I have an issue with it working correctly.

Basically, now it redirects the user even if he enters incorrect details, like Name: JHKJHKhj and Email: jkhkjhkjhkhjk

If he enters these details like that (incorrectly) he should get on the error page which is set by Aweber, but now he gets redirected anyways.

So this is how this should work :

1. User enters details properly, he gets redirected and cookie sets in.
2. User enters details incorrectly, he gets the default Aweber error page and he is not redirected.

Here is my code now:

```
>      $(document).ready(function() {
>         $('#subscribe1').show() 
>         
>           if (!readCookie('hide')) {
>           }
>         
>           else {
>             window.location = "http://website/whatever"
>           }
>         
>         
>           $('#sendbtn').click(function() {
>             window.location = "http://website/whatever"
>             createCookie('hide', true, 365)
>             return false;
>           });
>         
>         });
>         
>         
>         
>         function createCookie(name,value,days) {
>           if (days) {
>             var date = new Date();
>             date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
>             var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
>           }
>           else var expires = "";
>           document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
>         }
>         
>         function readCookie(name) {
>           var nameEQ = name + "=";
>           var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
>           for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
>             var c = ca[i];
>             while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
>             if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
>           }
>           return null;
>         }
>         
>         function eraseCookie(name) {
>           createCookie(name,"",-1);
>         }
```

And here is a part of the Aweber code

```
<form method="post" class="af-form-wrapper" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl"  >
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="meta_web_form_id" value="522321120" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_split_id" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="listname" value="jenselter" />
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://website.com/whatever" />

<input type="hidden" name="meta_adtracking" value="My_Web_Form" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_message" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="meta_required" value="name,email" />

<input type="hidden" name="meta_tooltip" value="" />
</div>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for cookie management google has a light javascript file named jcook.js
http://code.google.com/p/jcook/downloads/detail?name=jcook.js

download the file and use it.

i am giving a small example to do similar task.

your form will look like this for the input of name and email.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl" id="inputForm">
    <input name="name" />
    <input name="email" />
    <button id="authorize">authorize</button>
</form><!--end of the form-->
```

your jquery will be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#authorize").click(function(){
        var name = $("input[name='name']").val();
        var email = $("input[name='email']").val();

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://www.aweber.com/scripts/addlead.pl",
            data: {name: name, email: email},
            async: false,
            success: function(data){//when you will get the successful authorization
                COOKIES.createCookie("hide", true, 365);//COOKIES IS AN OBJECT IN THE JCOOK.JS TO MANAGE COOKIES
                window.location.href = "http://website/whatever";
            }
        });            
    });

    //if cookie exists
    if(COOKIES.readCookie('hide') != null){
        window.location.href = "http://website/whatever";
    }
});
```

Comment: if your redirection page and form submittion page is same then you can directly use the $("#inputForm").submit();

Comment: i think you are missing the jquery.js library in your page. first add it please.

Comment: and use the button tag instead of the <input type="submit" />. because if you will use the input tag with submit type it will submit on click event. but you are binding event with jquery. so remove the input tag and use button tag.